# Using node.js / express / yields / co / postgres do we connect to database on every client connection?

Tags: node.js, express, co

I am wondering if when running pg-co with node express server, do you connect to the database on every client connection? or keep a global connection?

Reference: https://github.com/basicdays/co-pg

In other words, here is my node module:

```
module.exports.set = function(app, worker_id) {

   var ms = require("mslibmod"),
      co = require('co'),
      async = require('async'),
      pgconn = require('pgconn').create(),
      pg = require('co-pg')(require('pg')),
      exec = require('co-exec'),
      thunkify = require('thunkify');

    app.get('/getLines', function(req, res, next) {
        var id = req.param('id');

        co(function*() {
            try {
                var pgHandle = yield pg.connect_(pgconn.dbserver('galaxy'));
                var statement = 'select business_name FROM business_info WHERE business_id = ' + '1016';
                var result = yield pgHandle[0].query_(statement);
                pgHandle[1]();  // pg queue done
                if (result.rows[0] == undefined){}
                ms.log(result.rows[0].business_name);

            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Panic: ' + e.toString());
            }
        })();

        res.send({});
    });

};
```

notice how I run the command:

```
var pgHandle = yield pg.connect_(pgconn.dbserver('galaxy'));
```

everytime a new express client is connected, is this the correct approach?
wouldn't lead to memory leaks?

Comment: According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg, node-postgres has built-in connection pooling support.

Comment: that's what I was suspecting, but just want to confirm that is the correct approach... regards!